# SQL Data Represented in Excell (Cells out of Order)

Tags: sql, excel, cell

Currently we are using excel to display our stored procedures for reporting.
I have been coming across an issue where the excel columns, once filled with data, are not in the same order as they're in the SELECT statement.

The CONNECTION STRING in excel, points to our database and the COMMAND TEXT is an execute call for the SP.
Its my understanding that excel will display the SELECT statement items in order of appearance.

Could someone confirm this or tell me if there is something I am missing?

Cheers
Skitlz

Comment: Without an ORDER BY, the results of a SELECT statement may be returned in *any* order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your ORDER BY sequence match the SELECT sequence and it should work, don't just match one, match them all.

I used to use SQL as an ODBC link inside excel and it was fickle at times!

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `ORDER BY "something in your table"` in the end of your statement `COMMAND TEXT` and see if you get the results in the order of the "order by".

Comment: Apologies, I should have checked my wording, I have edited the above.
The issue is not with the rows, it actually with the columns.

The columns are not appearing in the same order as the select statement.